# How do I change the way syntax warnings for a missing semi-colon (red squiggly lines) are generated?

Tags: intellij-idea

I love the fact that IntelliJ evaluates my code for syntax errors, but I don't like that it shows common errors on the current line as I'm typing.

There are several examples of this, but the most common one is the red error line (squiggly underline) for a missing semi-colon. I don't want the editor to check for this error until after I've finished typing the line and have pressed return. In fact, I really don't want the editor to evaluate the current line for ANY syntax errors until after I've completed it. The constant changing of the error indicators on the current line as I type is getting annoying.

I've looked around in the various options, but I can't seem to even find the name of squiggle line feature. It isn't code analysis, as that applies to the red and yellow indicators in the right margin. What is the name of this feature, and where can I find the options for it?

Example ( '|' is the current carrot position, '~~' are the red error lines)

```
System.Out = |
           ~~
```

The issue isn't limited to just the semi-colon, but for all sorts of other common syntax issues that I know I know about and will fix before moving on to the next line.

Update: I think the name of the feature is "error highlighting". But I still can't find any way to disable it for the current line. The closest I found was Setting --> Editor --> General --> Error Highlighting --> Reparse Delay, but that changed it globally with no option for just the current line.

Comment: To disable it for the current line -> make sure the current line is always correct ;)

Comment: Not actually a bad idea, except that IntelliJ never gives me that chance. I'd prefer not having to START each line with a ; then fill in the rest, lol.

Comment: Type faster ;) Or increase the setting to something more comfortable, 2000ms perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in IntelliJ IDEA to disable error highlighting for the current line.

Comment: Thanks. IntelliJ support confirmed and I submitted a feature request.

Comment: Could you please share the feature request link?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the Settings -> Editor -> General -> Error Highlighting -> Auto reparse delay (ms) to something more comfortable, e.g. 3000 ms.

It will still highlight the error, but not immediately.

Comment: The downside of this is that any highlighting stays until the next auto reparse -  even after the issue is fixed. So you usually still have some highlighting, it's just old.Unless you never stop typing when there are errors for more than 3 seconds :).